# How to prove that, for a linear projection $f$ we can find a number $M$: $||f(u)|| \leq M ||u||$. Is it also continuous?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, projection

To clarify the given question, we have $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ linear projection. How can we prove that we can find $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{align}
||f(u)|| \leq M ||u||, \ \forall u \in \mathbb{R}^{n}?
\end{align}
To clarify notation, we use $||.||$ for the Euclidean distance formula for $m$-dimensions. For example $||x|| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \ldots + x_m^{2}}$. We must also prove that $f$ is continuous. That every linear projection is continuous is trivial I think?

To prove the inequality, shouldn't we have any sort of upper bound to tie it to?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: All linear maps on finite dimensional spaces are continuous, hence bounded.

Comment: @geetha290krm surely by proving the inequality we can say that it's bounded, hence continuous? (I think it's an if-f relationship so it's ok)?

Comment: The components of $f$ are just linear combinations of the coordinates, So continuity is easier to prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mark's answer gave me a hint, and I took the rest.

We can prove that
\begin{align}
|T(x)| \leq M
\end{align}
when $|x|=1$.

Taking the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$ we may write
\begin{align}
x = a_1e_1 + \ldots + a_me_m
\end{align}
where $|a_i| \leq 1 \ \forall \ 1 \leq i \leq m$. So we have
\begin{align}
|T(x)| &= |T(a_1e_1+\ldots+a_me_m)|\\
&= |a_1 T(e_1) + \ldots + a_m T(e_m)|\\
&\leq |a_1| |T(e_1)| + \ldots + |a_m| |T(e_m)|\\
&\leq |T(e_1)| + \ldots+|T(e_m)| = M.
\end{align}

So there exists $M>0$ such that if $h \neq 0$ we have
\begin{align}
\big| T \left( \dfrac{h}{|h|} \right) \big| \leq M\\
\implies |\dfrac{1}{|h|} T(h)| \leq M\\
\implies |T(h)| \leq M|h|.
\end{align}

To prove that a linear transformation is continuous, it suffices to notice
\begin{align}
|T(h)| \leq M |h|
\end{align}
so if $\epsilon > 0$ is given and $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then whenever $0 < |x-h| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{M}$ we can have
\begin{align}
|T(x) - T(h)| = |T(x-h)| \leq M |x-h| < M \dfrac{\epsilon}{M} = \epsilon.
\end{align}
Therefore by definition the linear projection is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The unit ball $B=\{u\in\mathbb{R^n}: ||u||\leq 1\}$ is compact, and since $f$ is continuous (continuity is easy to prove), the set $f(B)\subseteq\mathbb{R^m}$ is bounded. So take $M=\sup\{||f(u)||: u\in B\}$.

Can you show the required inequality holds with this $M$?

Comment: Is it enough to say that 
\begin{align}
d (x, y) = \sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)^2} \to 0\implies  |x_k - y_k| \le d (x, y) \to 0
\end{align}
concerning the continuity of the linear projection? (And now that I think about it, all projections in general)

Comment: @algevristis Every linear transformation $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^m}$ in general has the form $f(x)=Ax$ where $A\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is some matrix. So just write $A$ explicitly and it will be easy to see that $f$ is continuous. (what you wrote in the comment is indeed used here). In infinite dimensional normed spaces this argument fails by the way, in this case there are non continuous linear transformations.

Comment: It's ok I found it will post solution soon.